# How to merge two Win2k3 iis 6.0 servers into a single win2008 iis 7 server?

Tags: web-server, iis-7, iis-6, web-hosting, website

I have IIS 6.0 server A, and IIS 6.0 Server B.
I would like to webdeploy all the websites from both to a single IIS 7 Server C.
Server A holds websites in D:\websites
Server B holds websites in D:\Inetpub

Problem is when I try to export Server B sites via webdeploy, it wipes out server A sites in IIS. 
Is there a way to do this using webdeploy?